# Help me delete the last three chars of any string please!

Tags: c#, string

Test string:

```
the%20matrix%20
```

How can I delete the last three chars? Using this code gives me an out of index exception:

```
y = y.Substring(y.Length - 4, y.Length - 1);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Seems this isn't your REAL problem; if you want to remove that "%20", you should use:

```
string test = "the%20matrix%20";
string clean = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(test);

if (clean.Length > 2) // if you still want to strip last chars...
    clean = clean.Substring(0, clean.Length - 3);
```

Comment: +1 For teaching me something I didn't know (UrlDecode) and also giving a solution to what is most likely the real issue here.

Answer (score 4):

As dalovega said, you need the first parameter of Substring to be 0 and the second Length - 3.  As an alternative:

```
if(y.Length >= 3)
{
    y = y.Remove(y.Length - 3)
}
```

Comment: since he said 'any string' this seems to work fine, dont need to do the UrlDecoding.

Answer (score 3):

You want

```
y.Substring(0, y.Length-4)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delete the last three characters, you need the first parameter of your Substring method to be zero.

Comment: that answer is wrong, too - it is the right problem, but he will get everything but the last character ...

Answer (score 1):

You need to check that the string is at least 3 characters long first.

```
if (y.Length > 2)
{
}
```

As others have said the version of [Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc319581.aspx) you want parameters are `startIndex` and `length`.

Though what do you want to do with 1 or 2 character strings?

Answer (score 0):

I found this post from a search I was looking for. I had a delimiter I was building with a string builder, and concat and wanted to remove the last delimiter.

```
var delim = "{somedelimiter}";
var sb = new StringBuilder();
//concat the values into one string
foreach (var val in values)
{
    sb.Append(val);
    sb.Append(delim);
}
var finalValue = sb.ToString();
finalValue = finalValue.Remove(finalValue.Length - delim.Length);
```

Answer (score -1):

string.Remove(string.LastIndexOf(" stringTo "));

Comment: That's not exactly "any" string.